# How to take the difference of Last_Logout and Last_Login in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datetime, authentication

I want to calculate the time difference of the user's last login timing and last logout timing. I have 2 columns in my database: Last_login and Last_Logout
I am using ASP.NET C#, how to do it? should i do in sql or code? Can i use datetime function?

Comment: If you have stored last login and logout you can do it in code to find the difference

Comment: If you have access to both the strings, you can use `DateTime.Parse()`, or better yet, `DateTime.TryParse()` to be safe. After that a simple `DateTime1 - DateTime2` gives you a TimeSpan object (then it has days, minutes, seconds, etc to give you the interval)

Comment: Or if you prefer to use mysql code, there is a function [DateDiff](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp), or [TimeDiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) assuming both are DateTime or Date columns.